# semantically equivalent but simpler pattern regex to the following

Tags: regex

I have a program with hundreds of patterns similar to the following:

```
(^|\.|,|:|;|\"|-|‖|\[|\(|\{)m(z|y)aword(e|)(s|)($|\.|,|:|;|\"|-|‖|\]|\)|\})
```

That the first group and last group searches for a beginning and end respectively.

```
(^|\.|,|:|;|\"|-|‖|\[|\(|\{)  << beginning
($|\.|,|:|;|\"|-|‖|\]|\)|\})  << end
```

is there a simpler alternative pattern semantically equivalent to the above, the problem with the above solution is since there is a lot  of words that should meet this pattern, I have more than 500 of them so far, that makes the program very very slow.
Any help and suggestion is truly appreciated
Thanks.
Bid

Comment: Those characters in your patterns fragments should be put inside a character class. And the words you're looking for should if possible be put inside an alternation then surrounded by your beginning and search, resulting in a single regex for all searched words

Comment: `(e|)(s|)` is a crime against regex

Comment: Please understand I am not regex expert and I have certainly committed  many crimes as such.  to avid (e|)(s|) crime what do you suggest.  I am porting a program and trying to be as close as possible to the original version

Comment: @Bid I provided an answer.

Comment: Aaron, thanks for suggestion, the beginning and end of the words vary and cannot be put inside an alternation.  The only constant patterns in all these  is what I  mentioned above

Comment: @Bid Can you provide examples of other words which would replace the middle `m(z|y)aword(e|)(s|)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An equivalent and less intense regex would be:

```
(?:^|[.,:;"‖\[({-])m[zy]aworde?s?(?:[.,:;"‖\])}-]|$)
```

Notes:

- When possible, it favors character classes `[]` instead of boolean alternation ORs `|`
- Favor non-capturing groups `(?:)`. Capture groups cost resources so shy away from them unless you need to explicitly reference something.

[My regex performance sample](https://regex101.com/r/LEK9H5/1) - 11,000+ steps

[Your regex performance sample](https://regex101.com/r/Co4mIK/1) - 46,000+ steps

Comment: Here is another example:

Comment: another example:   (^|\.|,|:||"|-|‖|\[|\(|\{)k(u|ú)chen(e|)(s|)($|\.|,|:||"|-|‖|\]|\)|\})')

Comment: @Bid If you combine the centers via alternation then it only increases the regex cost marginally. See https://regex101.com/r/HWyWoV/1; it has an increase of only 1000 steps. This is considerably more effective than running each word individually which costs 11,000+ steps per word.

Comment: Thanks, I see the performance gain.  As of today, there 750+ words that has to be treated similarly.  Certainly combining all them in one statement will create a nightmare of readability and very difficult to maintain.  I am going to group the in blocks of 10 and take advantage of your solution.  Many thanks again.

Comment: @Bid Very nice. I'd be interested in hearing more details about the performance gain. Was it marginally faster or considerably faster?